# How to assign ID/KEY to the entity in Google Appengine Datastore, and how to retrieve based on key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Suppose I have a Post entity,using db.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
```

How can i assign ID to each blog post, and how to retrieve the post with the key
If my code is like this.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

[1: Specifying your own key name](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#specifying_your_own_key_name) (see also [Using Numeric Key IDs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#numeric_keys)):

```
new_post = Post(id="post12345",              # MUST be unique!
                subject="The Subject",
                content="blah")
key = new_post.put()
id = key.id()  # will be the "post12345" value we specified
```

[2: Letting Cloud Datastore generate an ID to use for the key](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#letting_cloud_datastore_generate_an_id_to_use_for_the_key)

```
new_post = Post(subject="The Subject",
                content="blah")
key = new_post.put()
id = key.id()  # will be a numeric ID generated by google
```

Regadless of the method used for creating the entity (using a specified or an auto-generated id), you can retrieve the object by id or by key, whichever you have handy (assuming both are available in the sample code below):

```
post1 = Post.get_by_id(id)
post2 = key.get()
assert post1.key == post2.key
```

Comment: It didn't appear in my notification. Thank you for help, and i'm sorry for this late response.